# 2D reaction-diffusion Schnakenberg Model normalization

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, mathematical-physics

I need to normalice this Schnakegnber model in 2D:

$u_t=D_u(u_{xx}+u_{yy})-u+av+u^2v\\
v_t=D_u(u_{xx}+u_{yy})b-av-u^2v$

We also know that $a,b>0$.

Then I know that I'll applied separation of variables in order to apply superposition and find a solution. The BIG question is that, in most of internet articles, one can find the normalizacion of this model but in 1D.

How can I normalice this model in 2D? (as presented in the equations above)

Comment: what is $D_u$ ?

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky $D=D(x,t)=D(u(x,t))$... also $D(u)=mu^{m-1}$ is the non-lineal speed of propagation

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky what I've thougth is to send:

$x->\frac{x}{M}, y->\frac{y}{L}$

Comment: where is $m$ a come from? what is $M$ and $L$? can you write $D_u(u_{xx}+u_{yy}) $ explicitly?

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky D is the diffusive constant

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky $M$ and $L$ are the height and width from the square tho form a meshgrid to solve thos PDE's numerically

Comment: so $D_u(u_{xx}+u_{yy})=m(u_{xx}+u_{yy})^{m-1}$ or what? and what is the small $m$? does $m=M$? please edit your question and clarify all this things including your attempt to solve it, then write a comment so I get a notification and come to see.